# Is it possible to replace just the garage door opener console?

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

My old house has a garage door system that must have been 20 years old. It has been working fine for many years. But recently my car got broken into and the remote is stolen. I have no way to re-program the currently one as it's the only one I have and I don't know if it's taking a new code or not. Also there seems to be no replacement in the market. My model is Sears 139.654021

Photos below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Question: The whole system including motor and chain are working fine. How can I just replace ONLY the console and its remotes?

Comment: I would look for someone else scrapping out the same model and selling or giving parts away. The sad fact is, many things become obsolete and you can no longer get parts for them. Check Freecycle.org or eBay for similar model parts.

Comment: In any case, change the code on your garage door, if you can. If you can't, then that's a strong reason to change the whole system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question and a really frustrating situation. We've all been there when we lose a part to something that works fine but is now obsolete and cannot get parts for, easily.

As ArchonOSX mentioned, your best bet is to find one on eBay, Craigslist etc. However, you would most likely need to get both the receiver and remote together and make sure they are paired unless you know how to program the remote which some older models are fixed and not easily done.

You could probably find a programmable replacement kit but that would most likely cost close to what you'd pay for a new unit in the first place.

I'd consider upgrading to a new system anyway as a 20+ year old system most likely does not meet Federal and State safety requirements with safety sensors.

And if your car happened to have been broken into in your garage or near your home where the thief knows where you live, they'd have easy access to your garage/home since they too have your remote.

Answer (score 1):

Many garage openers and remotes use a standard radio code for communicating, with the ID number programmed by a bank of DIP switches; you just have to set the remote's DIP switches to match the opener's. It sounds like your door, though, works with remotes that each transmits a unique ID, and your opener's controller can be taught that ID.

There are, however, "universal" remotes. For example, Liftmaster sells remotes that work with a broad variety of openers; if you check their [compatibility table](http://liftmaster.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/209/~/liftmaster-remote-compatibility) you may find one that works for yours. If you still have one working remote then you're probably in luck; a new remote can "learn" from the old one.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find my model in the table of Liftmaster. I just need to change the code or something so that the stolen remote is prevented from opening my garage.