# Reprogram new remote to garage door opener with dip switches

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

I was having a problem with my garage door remote stolen in this thread but now I think I found a replacement remote that may work.

[Is it possible to replace just the garage door opener console?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/94463/is-it-possible-to-replace-just-the-garage-door-opener-console#comment138098_94463)

The garage door opener console is Sears 139.654021. However the remote is Model 139.53779

[image]

[image]

I found a few replacement possibilities:

**390 1 Button Sears Craftsman Compatible Visor Remote Control**

[https://www.amazon.com/Button-Craftsman-Compatible-Remote-Control/dp/B008VVA352/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008VVA352)

AND

**Craftsman 53879 (more expensive)**

https://www.gatehousesupplies.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=53879-now-893_max&click=2&gclid=CjwKEAjw_LG8BRDb1JTxm8uP_UwSJADu_8pWLsockzvK2fVGdPfsUJGuF5k4Hn_stYmL_0Y8sZ905xoCz9nw_wcB

or http://www.ebay.com/itm/Craftsman-53778-Garage-Door-Opener-3-Function-Remote-Control-READ-DESCRIPTION-/152169658712?_trksid=p2352135.l4275

I open the console I found the dip switch. My questions are:

1. How do I reprogram the NEW remote and current (only) remote if I change the dip switch code? Is there a dip switch to sync with the console too?
2. Do I need to do anything at the motor box? I read some online reviews and they say the unit (but which?) must have a green button. What and where is it typically (console, remote or motor)?

Thanks

Comment: Door opener remotes of that vintage generally have fixed codes selected by the DIP switches. If you open up the opener body (probably just remove a door) you should see a similar DIP switch. Set the remote DIP switch to the same code.

Comment: Basically, either both will have DIP switches or neither will. If the opener has a green button, then the remote shouldn't.

Comment: So there are 3 things I want to confirm: (1) motor on the ceiling, (2) opener console, (3) remote. I open up the console and remote. The console (#2) has dip switch and the remote (#3) has no dip switch. Where is the green button supposed to locate? At the motor? If so I can change it to "sync" with the console. But then how do I re-program the existing remote and the new remote?

Comment: In this case, dip switches in the console but none in the remote, then I don't know. This is older than anything I remember. Sorry.

Comment: Read the manual that came with the replacement remote.  If you haven't bought one yet, then go online and download the manuals.